# Error : does not exist in the namespace 'Common' when i installed Quartz.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have a .Net 4.0 project, which has a class named `Common` to do somethings like getQueryString, GetKey, etc.

When I installed the latest Quartz.Net for my Project, I started getting error messages that I'm missing namespace `Common` in my project.

Here's the actual error message:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'QueryString' does not exist
>   in the namespace 'Common' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: So your project was working, then you installed Quartz, and now it's not?

Comment: @Rufus L: Yes, my project working , but after installed Quartz, it can't, every pages what have a code call object Common can't run and notice not exist namespace 'Common'

Comment: Are there any files/classes that you are using `Common`'s methods without a using declaration?  Is this the same project or an additional project within the solution?  You may need to add a reference to that other project if this is the case.

Comment: @JNYRanger: my Common class in additional project in the same solution.When i call full namepace class common as MyProject.Common that is OK. But my solution so big, about 5k+ places to need change, so i want to find another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quartz probably has a namespace or subnamespace called `Common` and now you have a conflict.

You can try to find every problematic instance and either remove the Quartz using OR qualify your class name fully (that means using the full name including it's namespace).

Or you could remove Quartz, rename your own class to something more fitting and non-generic than "Common" and then install Quartz again. The removal and reinstallation of Quartz will make it easier to rename your class using the rename class feature of Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, Quartz.Net uses Common.Logging

Comment: in the way rename my class, this is imposible, because in my solution has many projects and i only work in some of projects, so modify the function project is not allow.When i installed Quartz into my project, i only used some of object as :IScheduler,IJobDetail,ITrigger,StdSchedulerFactory. Nothing relate to Common object :(